# Set string as "1" after clicking a button

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf

I ahva a jquery dialog that has two buttons.

```
<div id="generatePinsDialog" title="Generate New PINs">

<input type="button" title="button1" id="button1" />
<br />
<input type="button" title="button2" id="button2" />
```

In my js file, I want to set the string vlaue ans pass it to a wcf method.

```
function OpenGeneratePINsDialog() {
$("#generatePinsDialog").dialog('open');
$.get('/MyServices/myService.svc/GeneratePINs/' + #button1.val()+'/' + #button2.value
```

}

The WCF method:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/.../GeneratePINs/{button1}/{button2}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public void GeneratePINs(string button1, string button2)
    {
```

Which means if button1 is clicked, then pass button1=1 and button2 =0
            if button2 is clicked, then pass button2=1 and button1 =0

Thanks for help. Also please help me to correct the writing of value of button1.

```
           #button1.Val() or $(#button1.Val())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    function OpenGeneratePINsDialog(e) {
        var b1=0, b2=0; 
        if(this.id=="button1"){
             b1=1;
         }else{
             b2 =1;
          }
          $("#generatePinsDialog").dialog('open');
          $.get('/MyServices/myService.svc/GeneratePINs/' + b1 +'/' + b2, function(response){

          });
      }
      $("#button1").click (OpenGeneratePINsDialog);
      $("#button2").click (OpenGeneratePINsDialog);
```

Comment: Psst... your IDs don't match your code: `if(this.id=="button"){` when you have `$("#button1")` and `$("#button2")`

Comment: Is the $.get complete? I mean sometimes I saw there is code success something like.

Comment: @Love You have to provide callback if you want any response from server. otherwise it is fine.I added a callback function you will get response inside the that function.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this  :

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(evt) {
    // setup default values for button (button2 clicked)
    var button1 = "0";
    var button2 = "1";
    // change to button 1 if that was the button pressed
    if (evt.target.id == 'button1') {
        button1 = "1";
        button2 = "0";
    }
    // execute the rest of your code
    $("#generatePinsDialog").dialog('open');
    // append the values of button1 and button2
    $.get('/MyServices/myService.svc/GeneratePINs/' + button1 + '/' + button2);
})
```

Note your `$.get` function isnt complete